# Relacionamento N para N

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Como devo fazer para criar um relacionamento N para N no C# .NET CORE NVC Utilizando o Entity framework 5(CODE FIRST) Segue abaixo as os MODELS

quero que toda vez que eu for cadastrar um usuario (Account) deverá ser selecionado 1 ou N clientes

Consigo fazer o relacionamento, mais quando vou gerar o Controler e a View baseado no modelo ACCOUNT não criar a opção de selecionar o cliente e nem de cadastrar

```
namespace Chamados.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Nome")]
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column("Email")]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column("Password")]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Column("AccountTypeId")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Usuario", Description = "Tipo de acesso do usuario")]
        public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }

        [Column("Ativo")]
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }

        [Column("Status")]
        public bool Status { get; set; }

        [Column("Created_at")]
        [Display(Name = "Data Criação", Description = "")]
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }

        [Column("Update_at")]
        [Display(Name = "Data Atualização", Description = "")]
        public DateTime Update_at { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Chamados.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("Status")]
        public bool Status { get; set; }

        [Column("Created_at")]
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }

        [Column("Update_at")]
        public DateTime Update_at { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```